# Outlook Addin - addFileAttachmentAsync not working on Office MAC

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Sorry for my English I am a French developer.

I need your help because I am having a problem integrating my solution with the addFileAttachmentAsync functionality on Office Mac because on other Office 365 online platforms or on Windows everything works.

Despite several attempts, I cannot integrate inline pictures into my message body on Mac.

Below is an example of testing integration that works everywhere except on Mac.

In the logs I have ID attached element with the status succeded but the pictures are corrupted.

When I analyze the source code of the message received I do not have any inline image in the email.

Are you reproducing this problem and what would be the solution? Why does this only happen on Office Mac?

```js
insertInlinePictures();

function insertInlinePictures(){
    var file_attachments_arr =
    [
        {
            "name" : "gold_puppy.jpg",
            "url" : "https://picsum.photos/200"
        },
        {
            "name" : "black_puppy.jpg",
            "url" : "https://picsum.photos/200"
        },
        {
            "name" : "white_puppy.jpg",
            "url" : "https://picsum.photos/200"
        }
    ];
    my_add_file_attachments_recursively_helper(file_attachments_arr, 0, "");
}

function my_add_file_attachments_recursively_helper(file_attachment_arr, index, message) {
    if (index < file_attachment_arr.length) {
        var file_attachment_obj = file_attachment_arr[index];
        Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync
        (
            file_attachment_obj.url,
            file_attachment_obj.name,
            {
              isInline: true,
              "asyncContext" :
              {
                  "message" : message,
                  "index" : index
              }
            },
            function (asyncResult)
            {
                var next_message = asyncResult.asyncContext.message + "id : " + asyncResult.value + " , " + "status : " + asyncResult.status + "<br>";
                my_add_file_attachments_recursively_helper(file_attachment_arr, asyncResult.asyncContext.index + 1, next_message);
                debug("<div><img height=150 width=150 src='cid:" + file_attachment_obj.name + "'></div>");
            }
        );
    }else{
        debug(message);
    }
}

function debug(message, details) {
  console.log(message, details);
  let log = "<div style=\"background:red;padding:5px;color:white;font-size:14px;\"> " + message + " </div>";
  if( details !== undefined ) log += "<div style=\"background:black;padding:5px;color:white;font-size:14px;\"> " + details + " </div>"
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setSelectedDataAsync(log, { coercionType: Office.CoercionType.Html });
}
```

Thank you very much for your help !